# How to use Bootstrap 4 in Angular 2? I am getting the following error in Command prompt

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-4

```
D:\angular-2-beta-boilerplate>npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm WARN package.json angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstr
ap"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2 does not satisfy its siblings
' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.14 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.0.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\angular-2-beta-boilerplate\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Just use: **npm install --save ng-bootstrap** to install the module. [LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap)

Comment: Please format your post and add a question and explanation. At the moment it is not suitable for SO